# Site Search is not working with Solr Master slave configuration

Tags: solr, content-search

We have set up the Master and Slave for Solr configuration. There is one master and two slave servers configured on different ports. Appropriate replication is configured. The load balance is in place so as we CD servers can be catered for all queries.

Checked and found that replication is there. Below is the Master and slave configurations. We are using only one code, itembucket.

```
<!-- solrconfig.xml for master instance -->
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
   <lst name="master">
       <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
       <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
       <!--If configuration files need to be replicated give the names here, separated by comma -->
       <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml</str>
       <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">0</str>
   </lst>
 </requestHandler>
<!-- solrconfig.xml in slave instances -->
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" > 
     <lst name="slave">
       <str name="enable">true</str>
       <str name="masterUrl">https://load-balanced-url/solr/itembuckets</str>
       <str name="pollInterval">00:01:00</str>
       <str name="compression">internal</str>
       <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
       <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The problem is when we search the web site, it gives error as mentioned below on log file.

```
WARN  Unable to connect to Solr: [http://SOLR_URL_:8984/solr/], the [SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException] was caught.
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrStatus.OkSolrStatus()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8984
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: can you open `http://SOLR_URL_:8984/solr/` url from your browser? Can you do the same on the CD server (or whichever server throws the exception)? If not, most probably either solr is not running on that port or firewall blocks access.

Comment: yes, we are able to open the `http://load_balancer_URL_:8984/solr/` from my browser. Also Checked, SOLR is running and showing as status as running.

Comment: Can you do the same if you open browser on remote desktop of the server which throws the exception?

Comment: yes, we are able to open the http://load_balancer_URL_:8984/solr/ from my browser. Also Checked, SOLR is running and showing as status as running on remote server as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue get resolved when we reconfigure SOLR server for SLAVE and provided the Load Balancer IP address we correct Core path. There was one extra (/) added to Service address at the end of address. That helps to resolve the issue. It has to be     http://load_balancer_URL_:8984/solr    instead of 
    http://load_balancer_URL_:8984/solr/